# can we process a view for a bad request?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm unable to render the form with error message if the request is bad using spring controller  and jquery-Ajax Jsp page.

if the response code is 200 I'm able to see the page but not for other response codes.

please look into code snippets 
  '

```
 /* jsp page */ 

 statusCode: {
       200: function(response) {
            $("#${tableDiv}").empty();
            $("#${tableDiv}").html(response);
       },
       400 :function(response){
            showErrorMessage("OOPS! Donor Code is Already Assigned");
           $("#${addDonorCodeForm}").empty();                                
           $("#${addDonorCodeForm}").html(response); //can't load the response here       
       }
   }
```

/*Spring Controller snippet *?

```
 if (result.hasErrors()) {
                  modelAndView.setViewName("donors/donorCodes/addDonorCodeForm");
                  modelAndView.addObject("addDonorCodeForm",form);          
                  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
              return modelAndView;

                 }
```

can anyone suggest me any idea for processing the view even for bad requests.

Comment: Maybe the error response is structured slightly differently from the successful responses. What do you mean you "can't load the response" - is it empty, null, or just doesn't look the way you expect it to? Can you post a JSON of what the response looks like in each case?

Comment: I will check this printing the response to log and let you know. Thanks Misha